# Twilio Outbound Call API - How to place records on outbound call receiver's voicemail?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Suppose I am placing automatic call to restaurant owners for orders, if restaurant owners did not pick up the phone, I want to record the TWIML Response and place into restaurant owner's voicemail. I have seen documentation about voicemail for inbound call, but how to do for outbound call?

```
router.post('/voice', (request, response) => {

  var parentSpeech = request.query.parentSpeech

  const twiml = new VoiceResponse();

  /** helper function to set up a <Gather> */
  function gather() {

    const gatherNode = twiml.gather({ numDigits: 1 });

    gatherNode.say(parentSpeech);

    // If the user doesn't enter input, loop
    twiml.redirect("/twilio/voice?parentSpeech=" + parentSpeech);
  }


  // If the user entered digits, process their request
  if (request.body.Digits) {
    switch (request.body.Digits) {
      case '1':
          twiml.say('You have accepted the order. An email notification will be sent to you and customer shortly. Thank you for using FoodieBee and have a nice day!');
          break;
      case '2':
          twiml.say('You have rejected the order. An email notification will be sent to you and customer shortly. Thank you for using FoodieBee and have a nice day!');
          break;
      default:
          twiml.redirect("/twilio/voice?parentSpeech=" + parentSpeech);            
          break;
    }
  } else {
    // If no input was sent, use the <Gather> verb to collect user input
    gather();
  }

  // Render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  response.type('text/xml');
  response.send(twiml.toString());
});
```

Above is the code that works fine when restaurant owner pickup the phone. I am trying to place this twiml response into receiver's voicemail if they didn't pick up the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure if you still need it but Param MACHINE DETECTION = DetectMessageEnd seems to be what you need.